# Simple emulator programming: dec and hex

Tags: hex, decimal, emulation

Notch's DCPU-16 specs recently sparked my interest in the area of simple computer emulation, and just for fun I wanted to make my own.

However all the articles I could find ([such as this one](http://c64-retro-coding.blogspot.com/p/writing-6502-emulator-in-net.html)), while very informative, constantly switch between decimal and hexadecimal. For example, this code:

```
private void Initialise() {
    ram = new byte[0xFFFF];     // (64K)
    rom_kernel = new byte[8192];
    rom_basic = new byte[8192];
    stack_ptr = 0x01FF;         // The 256 byte stack is stored at $0100-$01FF (starts at $01FF)
    PC = 0x00;                  // Program counter starts at $0
}
```

**Why even use hex in the first place? Wouldn't this code be much easier to use?**

```
private void Initialise() {
    ram = new byte[65535];     // (64K)
    rom_kernel = new byte[8192];
    rom_basic = new byte[8192];
    stack_ptr = 511;         // The 256 byte stack is stored at 256 - 511 (starts at 511)
    PC = 0;                  // Program counter starts at 0
}
```

I feel like there's something I'm missing here but I'm completely new to this whole thing. Please instruct me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't *do* anything different, the compiler crunches them all to binary anyway. It's just a matter of taste and clarity. For colors, hex is much more readable, for example [green](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#GREEN): **-16711936** vs **0xff00ff00**...